# elem.setAttribute in jQuery breaking SSL (mixed active content error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, ssl, https

Can someone explain this error caused by my slider plugin that breaks my SSL for the home page:

> The page at 'https://...' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed
>   insecure content from 'http://....

In Firebug I get this particular error pointing to a particular line in jQuery.js:

> Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "http://...
>
> elem.setAttribute( name, value + "" );

This is jQuery 1.8.3. I don't want to use jQuery 2.0 because of the IE8 errors, plus it breaks my lightbox plugin.

Comment: That's not jQuery, and the issue isn't related to jQuery at all. You're loading images (probably?) with a `http` protocol in a site that has a `https` protocol.

Comment: I see what you mean, but why would Firebug point to that line in jQuery as the source of the error?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because as your web page uses HTTPS, ["all active mixed content delivered via HTTP on this pages will be blocked by default"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/fix_website_with_mixed_content#How_to_fix_your_website).

To add more clarity, "mixed active content" is ["content that has access to all or parts of the Document Object Model of the HTTPS page"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent#Mixed_active_content)

Hence to fix this error you need to make sure that you are using references (e.g. javascript files) which are served using HTTPS. If they are on your own website you should be able to just change the source link from "http" to "https". If they are hosted at a remote, look to see if they are also available via HTTPS.

Comment: yes, I understand that, but what I don't understand is why Firebug is pointing to that one line in jQuery.js `elem.setAttribute( name, value + "" );`